# Honda Accord Hybrid 2017 blinking red light on instrument panel

Tags: honda, accord, hybrid, warning-light, instrument-cluster

The vehicle is a 2017 Honda Accord Hybrid, purchased new in California.

Last night, after locking the vehicle in the driveway, a slowly-blinking red LED appeared on the instrument panel. The light is just above the left turn indicator light, and can be seen on this screenshot from the car's Owner's Manual:

[image]

The illustration shows the light, but I cannot find in the manual any mention or discussion in the text of the light's function.

When I'm sitting in the vehicle with the remote key in my pocket, the light stays off. I opened and firmly reclosed all doors, the trunk, and the hood to make sure they were securely closed. They were. When I manually lock the vehicle using the remote fob, the light begins blinking again. No other error messages or lights are illuminated, and the car starts and drives correctly.

What does the light indicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd bet a lot of money that that light indicates that the anti-theft system in the car is activated - meaning that the alarm will go off if someone tries to break in.

This would explain why it's only activated when you're out of the car and the doors are locked. The light looks exactly the same as on my Jeep.

Comment: Thanks, that seems right...although it's very strange that no one ever noticed it before. The VW Passat and Jetta that I've driven since 2001 have a light on the door panel that behaves the same way.

Comment: Chrøme for the win! I found another drawing in the owners manual that identifies the light as "Security System Alarm Indicator." I'll tick the green check mark tomorrow when it's available to me. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could be of service! Now you know to look for this light the next time you find yourself breaking into a car ;)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right, Chrøme.